# PHP & MySQL: PEAR:MDB2 or mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, pear

I noticed that the MDB2 library isn't updated anymore.

Should I remove it and start using the native mysqli extension?

Moreover, will using the native extension instead of MDB2 will impact performances of my queries?

Answer (score 2):

Use pdo:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

It's pretty much becoming the standard. Use parameter binding judiciously to avoid sql injection.